# How to use cssjanus

Tags: css

There was a site [CSSJanus](http://web.archive.org/web/20130601051135/http://cssjanus.commoner.com/) in Google Code used to flip direction from **ltr** to **rtl**.

At the bottom of the page, they said:

```
 You could also embed this webapp directly in your markup with your publicly accessible CSS files like so:

    <style>
      @import "/do?file=www.yoursite.com/yourcss.css";
    </style>
```

Can someone explain me how do I use it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, include the following in your HTML:

```
<style>
  @import "http://cssjanus.commoner.com/do/?file=www.yoursite.com/yourcss.css";
</style>
```

I'd just put it below any other CSS files you include on the page.

Make sure to provide the absolute path to your CSS file (like in the example) and not a relative one (like `css/style.css`).